# Adding different text to HTML layout depending on page (using Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, text-rendering, html-rendering

I feel like I am missing something here, and am pretty new, but here goes nothing.

I am building an app using Ruby on Rails and have 4 pages with the same html layout but the only difference is the content of the text. What are the recommended best practices for rendering the text content within the html layout so that there needs to only be one html file instead of the 4. The text is not stored in the database (otherwise I would just use {#What_I_Need}). One developer I talked to mentioned you could use .yml files for this purpose, but I haven't been able to make sense of (or really find) any tutorials on this.

Thank you!

For example:

```
  #rooms
    .nameofthispage
        .icon
            .fa.fa-iconforthispage
            .fa.fa-iconforthispage
        %h2 Heading for this page
        %p Lots of text for this page
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the values of the text in an instance variable in each controller method.

Then just write the instance variable in the template.

```
<%= @whatever_your_variable_is_called %>
```

Comment: How does this work when some of html is also custom (just a different class name for the page)? I am getting an error because it is being passed as plain text instead.

Comment: Can you paste in some examples?

Comment: Don't really know how else to share the code since mini-Markdown is so limited, so I just put the code in the html area of a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zapcaz/6hbu48Lr/1/) Thank you!